# java annotation to create all possible constructors

Tags: java, constructor, annotations

I am a newbie at java and exploring annotations.
I was wondering if there is any annotation in java that on applying to class, i can get all possible constructors.
Eg:

```
Class MyClass {

     int a;
     double b;
}
```

this should automatically allow me to have following 4 constructors

```
MyClass() {}

MyClass(int alpha) {
     a  = alpha;
}

MyClass(double beta) {
     b  = beta;
}

MyClass(int alpha, double beta) {
     a  = alpha;
     b  = beta;
}
```

I understand that different task require different processing in constructor but then we can always override these, right?

updated the code.

Comment: An example of an annotation i am using is @groovy.transform.ToString(includeNames = true)

This gives me an easy to use well defined toString() function

Comment: annotations aren't IDEs

Comment: I don't think you can do this two MyClass(int) {} ...

Comment: @StackFlowed, right my bad there but if b was a double, then this would have worked

The idea i am trying to share is an independent constructor for each property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotation will not create a constructor for you. Some third party library like [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) may help you creating contructors (not *all possible ones* though), accessors etc... with annotations, but you will need to change the compilation process (with a maven plugin or an IDE plugin).

Comment: Hi @dotvav

Thanks for youre response, i am using maven already and using IntelliJ as IDE. But i didnt get your reference with respect to lombok.

I am currently using lombak for getters and setters.

Comment: Then you should look into the `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html). The `@Builder` annotation may also help you with larger combinatory possibilities [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html).

Comment: Thanks @dotvav...

That was a great pointer...
Builder helps me achieve exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no there isn't any such annotations. In that sense: there are **no** annotations at all that would allow such kind of "source code introduction". The only option there would be something based on "aspect oriented programming", see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for details.

Besides: if you think about it; how many good usecases would you find for such an annotation?

Final note: I consider "annotations" to be a more advanced topic in the Java curriculum. I would recommend to start with "all basics" first (like: understanding what is possible with Java constructors, and what is not); before trying go work on any such advanced topic.

Comment: Hi 

I have updated the code, my bad for putting in the wrong code.